# File definitely exists. Get "No such file or directory" when trying to run it

Tags: bash, shell, arch-linux, executable

This is on Arch Linux. Take a look at this:

```
[saint-llama@hubs bin]$ lsattr
--------------e----- ./install_fnp.sh
--------------e----- ./toolkitinstall.sh
--------------e----- ./FNPLicensingService

[saint-llama@hubs bin]$ file FNPLicensingService 
FNPLicensingService: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped

[saint-llama@hubs bin]$ ldd FNPLicensingService 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcbafd8000)
        libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f870ce06000)
        librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f870cdfb000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f870cdd9000)
        libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f870cc93000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f870cc79000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f870cab2000)
        /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f870ce60000)

[saint-llama@hubs bin]$ sudo ./FNPLicensingService 
sudo: unable to execute ./FNPLicensingService: No such file or directory
```

So it exists for sure. Ldd shows all the libs are linked. File shows that it's a 64bit elf (and I'm on a 64bit install).

What gives? Why am I getting "No such file or directory"?

Comment: Im not into programming. Is it possible, that this is an object file with the `.o` missing? Such aren't executable.

Comment: It's probably because dynamic loader that this binary requests is missing. Post output of `ls -l /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3`

Comment: @mosvy: OP also posted output of `file FNPLicensingService `

Comment: @mosvy: ok, `ldd` wouldn't work but `file` does not use `ldd`. I've also checked it with `patchelf`.

Comment: @mosvy: yes, exactly. This is why I asked OP to check if dynamic linker shown by `file` really exists on their filesystem.

Comment: I believe all of those files dynamically linked did exist. Installing LSB related libraries fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command fixed it for me on Arch Linux allowing me to run the elf binary:

`sudo pacman -Syy ld-lsb lsb-release`

For other flavors of linux,

You should either install the [ld-lsb package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/ld-lsb/) (or `lsb-compat` or any similar package which contains `ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3`) or create a wrapper / executable script that starts your program via the existing dynamic linker:

```
#! /bin/sh
/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./FNPLicensingService "$@"
```

> What gives? Why am I getting "No such file or directory"?

That's a well known wart. Despite displaying the path of the binary, the error message is about the dynamic linker / ELF interpreter required by the binary not existing, not about the binary itself.

The output of `ldd` does NOT tell you if the dynamic linker really exists; `ldd` nowadays uses a dynamic linker from a list of "safe paths" instead of that burned in into the binary, in order to prevent users who run `ldd` on random binaries from harming themselves. And its output is also confusing and misleading in the case of binaries whose interpreter doesn't exist. Simple example:

```
$ cp /bin/sh /tmp/sh
$ patchelf --set-interpreter /no/such/file /tmp/sh
$ /tmp/sh
bash: /tmp/sh: No such file or directory
$ ls /tmp/sh
/tmp/sh
$ file /tmp/sh
/tmp/sh: ELF 64-bit LSB ..., interpreter /no/such/file, ...
$ ldd /tmp/sh => /foo/bar => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
...
        /no/such/file => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc60d225000)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be that sudo executes only commands that exist in directories specified in the `secure_path` in the `/etc/sudoers` or in `$PATH` if `secure_path` is not set. Although in this case the usual error message is `command not found`.

You could try to add the directory with an executable to `secure_path` and see how that goes.

Also make sure that the file has an executable bit set: `chmod +x FNPLicensingService`

Answer (score 0):

After Google, I suspect this command is just refusing to run from the command line, and faking that message.

https://community.flexera.com/t5/FlexNet-Publisher-Knowledge-Base/How-long-does-FNPLicensingService-normally-stay-running-after/ta-p/5516

> Question Because the licensing service isn't a 'service' on a Mac (we
>   use install_fnp.sh to generate a setuid-root binary that **gets
>   invoked by Flex-enabled applications via our libraries**), this brings
>   up the question, how long does FNPLicensingService normally stay
>   running after the last client disconnects?

There are also bunches of warnings that malware is often associated with this software. Caution advised.